# Is there any difference between microplastics from health perspective?

Tags: human-biology, health, environment

I wonder if there is difference between plastics if we talk about the negative health effects of microplastics. For example wood is just a bunch of polymer and some other components from chemical perspective and it is neutral from health perspective if it is not fungus infected. So I wonder if the polymer type matters by microplastics or it is just the size and maybe endocrine disruptor additives like BPA.

Comment: What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not simply to be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Comment: @MattDMo Well I found some article that talks about different polymer types and has a hazard model, but it is for marine life. I did not find an article which assesses human health risks of different polymers. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030438942200187X I found another article for human health, but it is too general, no cell tests, etc. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40572-018-0206-z

Comment: it would be helpful to have those citations directly referenced in the question, noting your specific objections to each and why they don't answer the question.